# How to make a button click add selection in react-select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to get a react button to "make a selection" in a react-select multi input dropdown.

I want my application to allow users to select items from both the drop-down and through the button. When the button is clicked however, it the react-select (dropdown) element should show the value selected by the button. It makes functionality more intuitive for my specific use case.

This is what my select (multi-dropdown from react-select module) and button components look like:

```
<Select
  options={props.options}
  isMulti
  onChange={handleDropdown}
  placeholder={props.placeholder}
/>

<Button
  onClick={addSelection}
/>
```

This is what my functions look like:

```
  const handleDropdown = (selected) =>{
  
  //Saving the array of selected items into a variable (selected_values)
  selected_values = selected
}

  const addSelection = (event) =>{
  
  //make dropdown value "car" appear as selected in select component (dropdown)
}
```

So far, I am kind of lost. I'm pretty new to the React way of doing things.

I have tried using refs in order to target the dropdown, but it doesnt yield any results. The react-select module documentation reccomends [modifying component props](https://react-select.com/advanced#action-meta) in order to access their dropdown actions, but this doesnt work for my particular case, as I cant use it from an external component (the button I want to use).

I appreciate any response that may help me work towards a solution. A push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have to pass value attribute to Select component. Did you forget it or is  there another way?

Comment: @PranavanJegatheeswaran you're absolutely right. Thank you so much! It's been a really intense week and I wasn't thinking straight. Hope you are doing well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some reconsideration and some help from the comments, this is the solution to this particular problem:

**This solution is for a class component**

Component tags:

```
<Select
  value={this.state.selectedValues}
  options={this.state.options}
  isMulti
/>

<Button
  onClick={this.addSelection.bind(this)}
  {/* Working in a class component, so "this" was added, and it was binded
      in order to be able to access it in its addSelection function */}
/>
```

Function:

```
  //Part of class component:
  addSelection () {
  this.setState({selectedValues: {value: 280, label: "Car"}})
  }
```

Basically, we are setting the value of the dropdown to be held inside a state (**selectedValues**). From there, we can modify its value through the click of a button external to the Select Component. Once states are modified, they trigger a re-render of components, which in turn updates the value of the dropdown component.